# How do I call async function inside redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have followed this [tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#using-the-redux-thunk-middleware) and I think I have done everything as required however I still have this warning:

> Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions. See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware and https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#using-the-redux-thunk-middleware for examples.

My code:

1. Inside folder `store` this is my `index.js` file:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";

const composedEnhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)); 
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancer);
export default store;
```

Inside my `App.js` file:

```
...
import store from "./redux/store/index";
...
return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <MainNavigator />
          </NavigationContainer>
        </Provider>
      );
```

Inside my `MainNavigator` file:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import {someAsyncFunctionFromRedux} from "../../redux/actions/index";
...
const MainComponent = (props) => {
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    async function f() {
      await props.someAsyncFunctionFromRedux();
    }
    f();
  }, []);
```

Inside my `actions/index.js`

```
export async  function someAsyncFunction() {
   return  async (dispatch) => {
     await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .get()
      .then( (snapshot) => {
        let users = [];
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const id = doc.id;
          users.push({id, ...data})
        })
        dispatch({ type: USERS_STATE_CHANGE, users });
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the issue but you shouldn't need to `await` a promise-ified function. Try removing either the `await` or  the `.then()`

Comment: are other thunks - even if not `async` - are working fine? maybe I miss something but to me it seems like `redux-thunk` is not enabled to the store for some reason

Comment: Even if you are using legacy Redux, please still don't use the `connect` method method, but the `useDispatch` hook instead. `connect` is only a legacy compatibility layer for legacy class components. Generally though, keep in mind that, as this tutorial states mutliple times throughout, it only shows Redux internals, not how you should write Redux nowadays. For that, please follow the "Redux essentials" tutorial from the same site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the issue is, since the code you have provided is not consistent: in `MainNavigator` you are importing a `someAsyncFunctionFromRedux` but your example code only has a `someAsyncFunction`. If it is the same function and just the example is wrong then the problem could be that you are returning an async function from an async function. Try this one (with some code improvements):

```js
export async function someAsyncFunction(dispatch) {
  const snapshot = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Users")
    .get();
  const users = snapshot
    .docs
    .map(({ id, data }) => ({ id, ...data() }));
  dispatch({ type: USERS_STATE_CHANGE, users });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The better way for using async functions with state management you have to use
Redux-Thunk middleware and it is best practice I think.

see blow link for documentation:

[Redux Thunk](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks)

Comment: That's way OP is doing.